# PHP Extension not working on Windows Azure

Tags: php, xslt, azure

I have just set up a Windows Azure website and I'm already having trouble making it work.
I have a PHP-website which works local on IIS for Windows 7 + MSSQL 2008.

The extension needed is pdo_xsl.dll and I have uploaded it using FTP to the wwwroot\bin folder.

Next, I have added the 'app settings'-string: `PHP_EXTENSIONS = bin\php_xsl.dll` in the Configuration tab for this site.

Then I saved and restarted the website but still got this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'XSLTprocessor' not found
```

Although the PHP INFO says:

```
xsl
XSL                                         enabled
libxslt Version                             1.1.27
libxslt compiled against libxml Version     2.7.8
EXSLT                                       enabled
libexslt Version                            0.8.16
```

I also use the URL method:

`http://website.com/index.php/module/action/value/`

It seems that Windows Azure is now seeing index.php as a directory instead of a file. As I'm using this method all over this script and it does work on IIS7 I would say it would work on IIS for Azure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already solved this problem on my own.
The solution is quite simpel actually...

In 'App Settings' add this:
PHP_EXTENSIONS on the left side.
bin/php_xsl.dll on the right side.
PHP_EXTENSIONS = bin/php_xsl.dll

So it needs the forward slash instead of the backslash.

Please notice that the XSL dll files are not working on any PHP version.
The current version is only working on 5.4 and for every php version you can find another dll-file. 5.5 does not have it's xsl dll as far as I know for now. Just as pdo_sqlsrv.dll btw.